# Ember.js - Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using `Ember.js` version `1.0.0-rc.3` and recently started seeing:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM. lib-   dev.js:28254
    Metamorph.checkRemoved lib-dev.js:28254
    Metamorph.html lib-dev.js:28224
    SimpleHandlebarsView.update lib-dev.js:29167
    (anonymous function) lib-dev.js:14424
    Ember.handleErrors lib-dev.js:10331
    invoke lib-dev.js:14422
    invokeOnceTimer lib-dev.js:14875
    (anonymous function) lib-dev.js:14424
    Ember.handleErrors lib-dev.js:10331
    invoke lib-dev.js:14422
    iter lib-dev.js:14492
    RunLoop.flush lib-dev.js:14546
    RunLoop.end lib-dev.js:14451
    tryable lib-dev.js:14652
    Ember.tryFinally lib-dev.js:11119
    Ember.run.end lib-dev.js:14655
    autorun
```

I have no idea where this is coming from, and how to start tracking it down. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a View where `checkRemoved` is used? But I guess without showing more code it will be difficult to debug...

Comment: Not calling `checkRemoved`, just grepped the project, only place it shows up is inside of Ember.js.

Comment: does it happen randomly? Or when does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

I think I tracked it down. It was because we were setting `.html()` with jQuery and blowing away:

```
 <script id="metamorph-XXX-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

Tags.

Comment: Yep. Ember doesn't like it when it goes to update a field that is suddenly missing.